# In app keyboard "Numbers" with 2 TextView

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

```
Button buttonClear;
private TextView inputValue;
private static final String DIGITS = "0123456789.";
private Boolean userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false;
```

here is some animation

```
TextView image1;
TextView image2;
TextView image3;
TextView image4;
TextView image5;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    inputValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ePrice);
    findViewById(R.id.button0).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button6).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button7).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button8).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.button9).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.buttonDecimalPoint).setOnClickListener(this);

    Button buttonClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);

    /** Backspace for in app keyboard */
    buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            inputValue.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
        }
    });
    /** Backspace */

    /** Disable Key API level 11 where suppose to disable the android keybaord i also tried to change the manifest but the keyboard still coming up */
    inputValue.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 ) {
        inputValue.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        inputValue.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    }

       image1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tPercent);
       image2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textPercent);
       image3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Percent_10);
       image4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Percent_pay);

       image5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ePrice);

       Animation animationFadeIn1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein_1);
       image1.startAnimation(animationFadeIn1);
       Animation animationFadeIn2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein_2);
       image2.startAnimation(animationFadeIn2);
       Animation animationFadeIn3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein_3);
       image3.startAnimation(animationFadeIn3);
       Animation animationFadeIn4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein_4);
       image4.startAnimation(animationFadeIn4);

       Animation animationFadeIn5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
       image5.startAnimation(animationFadeIn5);


    // here is first EditText which i can type normally which in app keyboard
    final EditText editPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ePercents);
    // here is second EditText where i can't type anything with in app keyboard
    final EditText ePercent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ePrice);
    // to get the 1 result 
    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewResult);
    // to get the 2 result 
    final TextView result2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewResultPay);

    Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
    buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    /**Here is some calculation happening **/

}

/**here is the onclick for buttons for in app keyboard**/

    public void onClick(View v) {
    /** Numbers */
    String buttonPressed = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
    if (DIGITS.contains(buttonPressed)) {
        // digit was pressed
        if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {

            if (buttonPressed.equals(".")
                    && inputValue.getText().toString().contains(".")) {
            } else {
                inputValue.append(buttonPressed);
            }

        } else {

            if (buttonPressed.equals(".")) {
                inputValue.setText(0 + buttonPressed);
            } else {
                inputValue.setText(buttonPressed);
            }

            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true;
        }
    }
    /** Numbers */

}
```

**What i want is:**

1. To disable the android keyboard.
2. I need to type in EditText with my made number buttons in each EditText's.. there is 2 EditText.

I tried to duplicate the onclick for digits but its writing in the same time in both EditText's

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

1/ For disabling android keyboard, make a class extending EditText, and apply it to your edittexts

```
editPrice.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

2/ For adding number to your editText

```
// On click on a digit button
editPrice.setText(editPrice.getText().toString().concat(String.valueOf(yourNumber)));

// For removing last char (in case of a delete button)
editPrice.setText(editPrice.getText().toString().substring(0, editPrice.getText().toString().length()-1));
```

Comment: I don't want to use specific numbers... i have a self made numbers keyboard.

Comment: i want to type numbers in first edittext and then in the second one and then calculate these numbers to get the result. and i want to do it with my keyboard not with android keyboard.